# Actionscript 3: Entire event dispatching becomes unusable

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on something similar to the Angry Birds "rollout" for options, etc., but I'm running into a fairly substantial problem.

The rollout itself is just a toggle button, with several other buttons added to the display list that move when you touch the toggle button. Each of these buttons is a class that extends Sprite and contains individual methods for touch events, begin, end and out. When these buttons get initialized (NOT instantiated), the touch begin listener is added. Something like this:

```
    public function Initialize():void 
    { 
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, OnTouchBegin, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    private function OnTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, OnTouchBegin);
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, OnTouchRelease, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, OnTouchOut, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    private function OnTouchRelease(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, OnTouchBegin, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, OnTouchRelease);
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, OnTouchOut);
    }

    private function OnTouchOut(e:TouchEvent):void
    {
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, OnTouchBegin, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, OnTouchRelease);
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, OnTouchOut);
    }
```

Then, when these buttons get hidden from the screen, a method is called to remove any of the listeners that are currently active on them:

```
    public function Deactivate():void 
    {
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, OnTouchOut);
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, OnTouchRelease);
        this.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, OnTouchBegin);

    }
```

This is just for the standard button functionality (up/down texture and sound), on top of this, when I make the game, in my rollout class, I have an additional method that will add another event listener for custom logic that should occur when the button is touched (the button itself is created elsewhere).

```
    public function AddRolloutButton(listener:Function):void
    {
        if (listener != null) 
        {
            _buttons[index].addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, listener);
        }
```

The buttons in the rollout itself are removed from the display list until they are to be shown. When the rollout is closed, the buttons are deactivated (removed from display list and the 3 button listeners within the button class are removed).

Everything works perfectly fine the very first time I open and close the rollout. After that, the event dispatching system just inexplicably dies. Every single InteractiveObject on the screen, regardless of position or type, becomes unusable. I traced out whether or not the listeners were still there on the rollout toggle button, and it was. I also confirmed that the rollout button itself was the only thing on the display list.

What I've noticed is that if I comment out the listener removal in the deactivate method of the button for the touch begin listener, or pass in null for the listener method in the AddRolloutButton method, everything works just fine. The issue seems to stem from having multiple listeners of the same type on the rollout buttons, and then removing one or all of them.

If anyone has any ideas of just what is going on, that would be very helpful. I was under the impression that adding multiple listeners of the same type to an InteractiveObject was perfectly valid.

UPDATE:

It appears that only TouchEvents get broken by this issue I'm having. I just tried using a mouse click listener on the stage after opening and closing the rollout, and that still works. So, only touch events are getting broken, if that helps at all.

Comment: Not a help, but the accepted convention in Actionscript is for Class members (methods and properties) to start with _lowercase_ letters. It's better to go with the standard, because if you hire someone new (or go to work on another team) everyone is on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this is a convention that has been adopted by the team I'm working in, since the majority of us all come from a C++/C# background. :)

Comment: Actually, the MS C# references all say that members should begin with lowercase, but all their examples show uppercase. However, as long as you never think you'll need to work on another AS team or hire an AS developer, then ok, whatever.

Comment: Typically, I create functions and class methods with an upper case for the first character, and we have decided within our team to start all private and protected class members (what you call properties) with an underscore followed by a lower case letter. We do not create public members, except in some outlying circumstances. As far as working in another AS team or bringing in another AS developer.. isn't conforming to the standards set by the team you're working in standard practice in the games industry?

Comment: I wouldn't want to work on a team where I'd have to change my coding style to one that's not best practice and that might give me problems on most other teams I might work on afterwards. I guess it depends on whether your company tends to attract"lifers" or not.

Comment: And who defines "best practice"? Some company head that says "this is the way we do things, and that's that", who can change at any time and create a new "best practice"? From my experience, the "best practice" is the one that gets the job done in the most efficient manner possible. I understand the importance of doing things in a way that is consistent with the way others do things, but it is not always the best option. Regardless, this is completely outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Anyways, I have determined the root cause of the issue I am having. If I remove the event listeners BEFORE removing the buttons from the display list, I get the problem. However, I changed the order of display list/listener removal such that the buttons get removed from the display list and then the listeners get removed, and the problem is solved. I believe this to be a deficiency in Adobe AIR/AS3/whatever, as I cannot fathom why it would matter which order you do those things in.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is something going wrong in your `AddRolloutButton` method. Are you sure you are assigning the correct listener function?

In your example the `listener:Function` argument should be equal to `_buttons[index]. OnTouchBegin`.

Or, since whatever class that owns the `AddRolloutButton` method seems to be in *control* of the buttons, you could potentially scrap the listener argument altogether since you *know* what method that needs to be triggered.

For example like this:

```
public function AddRolloutButton():void {
    var currentButton:MyButtonClass = _buttons[index] as MyButtonClass;
    currentButton.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, currentButton.OnTouchBegin);
    [...]
}
```

---

However, what you could do is to never remove the `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN` in the `Deactivate` function. The touch events will never be triggered when the DisplayObject isn't on the Display List. This means you don't have to worry about adding the listener every time you want to add the button to the Display List again.

If you set the listener to use a **weak reference** it will not hinder the button from being garbage collected when it's not needed anymore. To make your event listener use a weak reference, set the fifth argument of the `addEventListener` method to true.

`addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void`

```
public function Initialize():void { 
    this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, OnTouchBegin, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the listener function that is being added to the buttons in the rollout do not exist in the rollout class. They exist in another part of the program altogether (it must be this way), and that listener function is passed into the AddRolloutButton method and attached to the button. I know this works, because I've done it before.

Comment: Also, to clarify further since I am getting the idea that there is some confusion here, the OnTouchBegin, OnTouchRelease and OnTouchOut methods exist in the button class, and are managed by the button class. The listener function being passed into the AddRolloutButton class is an entirely different function altogether. Therefore, by the end of all the processing, there will be two touch begin listeners added to the button, that are added in separate parts of the program.

Comment: I have thought about not removing the listeners managed by the button class until the buttons are to be deleted, but I was thinking of memory management concerns regarding this. Also, this does not solve the issue of why the heck the entire event system is breaking because I am removing that listener.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the `Initialize` method again at some point after closing the rollout?

From your code it looks as though you remove all of the event listeners in `Deactivate` and then never add the `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN` listener again.

Comment: Yes, Initialize is called after the rollout is opened again. However, the rollout buttons themselves are not the issue. The issue is that after the rollout is closed, every single display object stops processing touch events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by removing the event listeners. Since the Button has a reference to the callback, it has a reference to that callback whether the listeners are attached or not. Are you thinking that adding a listener creates a reference from the callback to the button? It doesn't--the [reverse is true](http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html).

If you really want to have the Button release the callback when it is removed from the display list, then it can't hold that reference after it removes the listeners. Consider using something like [Supervising Presenter](http://blogs.adobe.com/paulw/archives/2007/10/presentation_pa_2.html) or a [RobotLegs Mediator](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/intro-robotlegs-pt1.html) to manage those dependencies.

I seriously doubt that the entire event system is being borked by what you're doing.

I'd be more inclined to believe that this:

```
        if (listener != null) 
        {
            _buttons[index].addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, listener);
        }
```

is failing, either because the button that's referenced is not the one that's actually on stage, or because listener is null..

I *have* seen times where adding and removing events with priorities can cause things to fail, but typically this is with events that aren't propagating on the display list.

One way that you can test this is simply to listen to the main document or the stage for touch events and see if you're getting those events. If the entire event system is borked, you won't get them, but if your listener logic is wrong, you will.

You may also want to check the willTrigger property on the button and event.

Comment: The point is to try to conserve memory. As I understand it, event listeners attached to a display object take up memory regardless of whether they are on the display list or not.

The AddRolloutButton function is working as intended. The external listeners are getting added correctly. When I open the rollout, I can tap the buttons on the rollout just fine, and the correct callbacks get fired. The issue is that once I open and close the rollout just once, all event listeners no longer work.

Comment: I just tried your idea of adding a touch listener to the stage, and it too fails completely after the rollout is closed.

I have done tests of using the hasEventListener and willTrigger functions to determine the state of my objects, and everything appears to be fine from that.

So.. yeah, the entire event system is borked for some reason.

Comment: Try it without the priority and see if that helps. The listeners won't get called if the object is not on the display list, so you're not losing any performance if you don't remove them. If the button has a reference to the function, it has a reference to the function, so the only way you'd conserve memory is to remove the event listeners _and_ null the reference to the callback. (IOW, your understanding is only correct if the instance doesn't also have another reference to the function other than the one created when you add the event listener.)

Comment: The priority wasn't there when I first started this. I put the priority in afterwards due to an issue that came up after the fact (external listener being fired before the internal listener that played the sound), but it had the same issue. I'll spend a bit more time trying to fix this, but failing that, what I believe I will do is just go back to what I was doing before (one listener per event type) and supply methods to swap the texture and play the sound. It's a bit more work when making a game, but at least it completely gets around the issue.